# Limit VPN login to members of a group

Tags: vpn, cisco, openldap

I'm running Cisco ASA5520's with PIXOS 8.2(1). I have my vpn setup to authenticate users from my ldap server. I need to be able to limit them to a specific group.
My login base dn is "dc=example,dc=com"
Users are in dn of "uid=$username,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"

I need to limit vpn access to people are are members in a group in a different OU.
The OU I need to check is "gid=vpn,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: I'm looking at using Reverse Group Membership's to see if that will allow me to be able to better manage this. According to the [documentaion](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html) That could do what I need.

Comment: Are you using Active Directory, or a different LDAP server?

Comment: I'm not using AD. Its an OpenLdap server. I did Figure it out. I'm doing a write up so I can answer the question for others.

Answer (score 1):

For our ASA, even though we have AD/LDAP, we still use RADIUS.  You may find this works beter.  I know that doesn't answer your question though.

With that being said, have you seen this article?  Looks pretty striaght forward.
https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-3843